# Get one sign after a searchstring and replace it

Tags: regex, notepad++

i was searching the web but i couldn't find a solution. may i don't even know how to search right because its hardly to define a question for searching in google.

i have a csv file with about 1750 lines.

**(my.csv)** e.g.

```
123456-123456;1aaaa;1bbbb;12.1;1cccc;1dddd;123;123abc
123456-123457;2aaaa;2bbbb;12.1;2cccc;2dddd;456;123abc
123456-123458;3aaaa;3bbbb;12;3cccc;3dddd;789;123abc
123456-123459;4aaaa;4bbbb;1.0;4cccc;4dddd;123.0;123abc
```

**GOAL:**
what i want to do is select the **;** after e.g. **.1** or **.0** or what ever is after the dot.

in the end i want to fill it with a 0 (zero) or replace the **;** with **0;** so i get

```
123456-123456;1aaaa;1bbbb;12.10;1cccc;1dddd;123;123abc
//............................^
```

or

```
123456-123459;4aaaa;4bbbb;1.00;4cccc;4dddd;123.00;123abc
//...........................^..................^
```

**TRYS:**
i tried this

```
(\.[0-9])(;)
```

but it select **.3;** (of course it does, but at least im almost at the right position)

**QUESTION:** can someone help me with the regex ?

Comment: On what line does it match `.3;`? I don't see that in your sample text. And why shouldn't it match `.3;`? What do you expect it to match instead?

Comment: The third line of your sample text does not have a decimal point--how do you want to handle that case?

Comment: its just a example  it matches the dot and the followed number + the ; ut i only want the ;

Comment: @mbroshi, yes i know... and that's a other task :D

Comment: @Dwza please check my modified answer. this should meet your requirements explained in comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a replace all in notepad++ for following regex
Find what: `(0-9-a-zA-Z\;)*([.]){1}([0-9]){1}([;]){1}(0-9-a-zA-Z\;)*`
Replace with: `\1\2\30\5`

**Explanation:** 
So since you wanted to preserve and replace a few digits, what we are gonna do is find text before and after what you want to replace, but then the thing we want to replace is a small part of what we can find and anchor to. So there has to be a five part regex.

**First and last parts** are everything digits and alphabets and semicolon

**middle part is :**  One period, followed by any number of digits and then one semicolon

Screenshot of working example attached here
[image]

Comment: sorry this selects way more than i want... i only want **.X;** and i want to replace it with **.X0;** i don't want to match or change **.XY;**

Comment: @Dwza OK. Changing the answer to match yor requirements

Comment: greate, thanks very mutch... saved me hours of work! :)

Comment: @Dwza I'm glad I could be of help! +1 to you.

Comment: did i ever sayed i love stackoverflow and its community ? :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48379/discussion-between-dwza-and-dhruvjoshi)

Answer (score 2):

To change any number with one digit after the decimal point to have two digits, replace `(\.\d);` with `\10;`. This only works for numbers followed by a semicolon.

To handle numbers at end of line or followed by a semicolon, replace `(\.\d)(;|$)` with `\10\2`. (Tested with Notepad++ 6.5.2)

If your question is specifically about the fourth field then replace `^([^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^.;]*\.\d);` with \10;`.

Comment: yes its about the fourth field but when i replace like this it turns the string from **12.1** to **120** but i want **12.10**

Comment: secont problem is, i have eg. **12.1;** if i replace it like you say it changes it to **12.0;** or if i modify the string to \.\100; it gives me **12.00;** but is MUST me **12.10;**

Comment: Check that the `\.`, the `\d` and the `)` are in the order shown in the answer. The replace worked fine for me in my test on the strings in the question.